# Find the Distance

Tags: pattern, logic-grid

The distances from you to some certain cities are written below:

```
  BERLIN 200 miles
  PARIS 300 miles
  ROME 400 miles
  AMSTERDAM 300 miles
  CARDIFF ??? miles
```

**How far should it be to Cardiff? please explain the logic you used to figure it out in your answer.**

Comment: Are the distances related the names of the cities?

Comment: yes, cities related to mathematically to distance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cardiff is:

> 100 miles away. The explanation is that each vowel's value is 300, whereas each consonant's value is -100

Answer (score 17):

If we take the question literally, we get the following:

> There is no place with those exact measurements to those locations. Even when using nautical miles instead of land miles, the distance between Rome and Berlin is more than 600 miles. However, if we draw circles with those distances centered on the cities, the intersections get pretty close somewhere in southern Germany. From there, it's about 550 nautical miles to Cardiff.
> Picture for clarification of my method:
>  [image]

Comment: It is some logical riddle not real distance you find out Cardiff distance by using above distances

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda expecting that. Just figured I should post this for completeness' sake.

Comment: "You're exhibiting two-dimensional thinking" -Spock.  Could the answer be somewhere inside the Earth?  Or in outer space?

Comment: @user2023861 Well, of course the earth is curved, but I don't think the curvature is enough to bridge the gap of distances between Berlin and Rome...

Comment: Yeah, I was disappointed that this was yet another letter-play puzzle instead of something fun and geographic.